# Most Efficient Cumulative Summation in numba?

Tags: python, performance, numba

I am attempting to use the most time efficient cumsum possible on a 3D array, in python. I have tried numpy's cumsum, but found that simply using a manual parallelized method with numba:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
from timeit import default_timer as timer

@njit(parallel=True)
def cpu_cumsum(data, output):
    for i in prange(200):
        for j in prange(2000000):
            output[i,j][0] = data[i,j][0]

    for i in prange(1, 200):
        for j in prange(1,2000000):
            for k in range(1, 5):
                output[i,j,k] = data[i,j,k] + output[i,j,k-1]
    return output

data = np.float32(np.arange(2000000000).reshape(200, 2000000, 5))
output = np.empty_like(data)
func_start = timer()
output = cpu_cumsum(data, output)
timing=timer()-func_start
print("Function: manualCumSum duration (seconds):" + str(timing))

My method:
Function: manualCumSum duration (seconds):2.8496341188924994
np.cumsum:
Function: cumSum duration (seconds):6.182090314569933
```

While trying this with guvectorize, I found that it used too much memory for my GPU so I have since abandoned that avenue. Is there a better way to do this, or have I hit the end of the road?
PS: Speed needed due to looping around this many times.

Comment: Are you aware that your first loop could be summarized as: `output[:,:,0] = data[:,:,0]`? Plus, numpy already has a method for cumulative sum, which is supported by numba as explained here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

Comment: Thanks, forgot about slicing. I know numpy has a function, which is slower than the method, and I can't pass np.cumsum into a jitted function because numba doesn't support the axis parameter in nopython.

Comment: Are your array dimensions fixed (or maybe only your last dim)? Maybe this can be done a bit faster (nested parfors are usually not optimal), but calculations like this will soon be limited by your memory bandwidth. The CPU can calculate sums usually much faster than the RAM can provide data. Therefore also a calculation (RAM->GPU calculation->RAM) makes no sense.

Comment: @BryceBooze Fair enough, if you need the axis option, then you cannot use numpy's `cumsum` method in numba. However, using numpy's slicing capabilities, you could already optimize your current method to contain a single loop.